# Refactoring: looping through hash(?) javascript

Tags: javascript

I made buttons, which refine the search according to some parameters.

```js
var count = 1;
document.getElementById("families").addEventListener("click", changeText);
function changeText() {
   if (count == 0) {
       document.getElementById("families").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Zeige Angefragt");
       count = 1
   } else {
       document.getElementById("families").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Hide Angefragt");
       count = 0
   }
};
document.getElementById("families2").addEventListener("click", changeText2);
function changeText2() {
   if (count == 0) {
       document.getElementById("families2").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families2").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Zeige Eingeteilt");
       count = 1
   } else {
       document.getElementById("families2").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families2").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Hide Eingeteilt");
       count = 0
   }
};
document.getElementById("families3").addEventListener("click", changeText3);
function changeText3() {
   if (count == 0) {
       document.getElementById("families3").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families3").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Zeige Abgesagt");
       count = 1
   } else {
       document.getElementById("families3").innerHTML = "";
       document.getElementById("families3").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Hide Abgesagt");
       count = 0
   }
}
```

It is clearly seen that this is the same function repeated for all three buttons.
How can I improve my code to pass parameters to function instead of copying it? May be i can have my ids and text in a hash, and then use text accordingly? 
I'm a newbie in javascript.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
function changeTextClickHandler(elementId, showText, hideText) {
  return function() {
    if (count == 0) {
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById(elementId).insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', showText);
        count = 1
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById(elementId).insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', hideText);
        count = 0
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("families").addEventListener("click", changeTextClickHandler("families", "Zeige Angefragt", "Hide Angefragt"));
document.getElementById("families2").addEventListener("click", changeTextClickHandler("families2", "Zeige Eingeteilt", "Hide Eingeteilt"));
document.getElementById("families3").addEventListener("click", changeTextClickHandler("families3", "Zeige Abgesagt", "Hide Abgesagt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` with **attribute selector**

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "[id^='families']") ).forEach( s => {
   s.addEventListener( "click", e => {
      var el = e.currentTarget;
      if (count == 0) {
         el.innerHTML = "";
         el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Zeige Eingeteilt");
      } else {
         el.innerHTML = "";
         el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "Hide Eingeteilt");
      }      
      count = (count + 1) % 2;
   })
})
```

Comment: please note that there are different strings used in each changeTextX() function

Comment: Thank you, but for each id i have its own text to show on a button

Comment: Create a map of that text against each id and then use the same.